# Debye temperature, Debye frequency, and Debye mass from dimensional analysis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, metals

What are some intuitive ways to obtain Debye frequency, Debye mass, and Debye temperature, using the naive dimensional analysis, without going through the details to work out the Debye model?

For example, can we take the copper as a model for the metal?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to perform dimensional analysis? If so, have you tried an internet search? What do you mean by taking copper as a model for "the metal"? What is "the metal"? This seems to be the wrong way round : real materials like copper are modelled by idealized objects like coupled oscillators.

Comment: Dimensionally, the Einstein frequency and the Debye frequency are the same. Quantitatively, they are the same order of magnitude. I do not see how one could avoid going through the details of the Debye model if one needs to improve on the Einstein model of independent oscillators.

Comment: @ sammy gerbil, if you are so good, why dont you provide a nice answer instead of voting down? No, you are either wrong or imprecise, the copper is not coupled oscillators in Deybe model -- you need to take into account the phonon modes beyond the Einstein model. If you are good enough, you should also try to compute the Debye frequency for BCS superconductor --- without going through the Mean-Field or self-consistency calculation of BCS wave function, but through the dimensional analysis and physical intuitions. This is what I looked for.